# C# Using Base Constructors with Semicolon

Tags: c#, syntax, constructor, semantics

When creating constructors in C#, that reference the super constructors of the inherited classes, why am I required to use curly brackets, instead of having the option to terminate the statement with a semicolon?

The question comes to mind, because I currently have an abstract class, which is inherited to easily return results from executed commands.

For example:

```
 abstract class CommandResult<T> {
    protected CommandResult() { }

    protected CommandResult(string msg) : this() {
        Message = msg;
    }

    protected CommandResult(string msg, T result) : this(msg) {
        Result = result;
    }

    protected CommandResult(T result) : this() {
        Result = result;
    }
 }
```

would be my abstract class.
In the class referencing to it, they currently would look like the following:

```
 public class CommandIntResult: CommandResult<int> {

    public CommandIntResult() { }

    public CommandIntResult(string msg) : base(msg) { }

    public CommandIntResult(string msg, int result) : base(msg, result) { }

    public CommandIntResult(int result) : base(result) { }

}
```

There is no logic in the body of the constructor.
What is the reasoning behind requiring the brackets, instead of having the option to terminate with a semicolon, as follows?

```
public CommandIntResult(string msg, int result): base(msg, result);
```

Comment: This feels like a question that can only really be answered by "Because that's what the spec says". Why the spec says that feels like it could only be answered based on speculation...

Comment: Semicolons are usually used to define abstract methods. `{}` tells the compiler that the method is implemented but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: You can add additional logic to the inherited class constructor. That's why curvy brackets are required. It's part of the C# syntax.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate of that question somewhere on SO with a satisfying answer (though probably still around "the spec says so", but I remember there was some syntactical reason). I just can't find it....

Comment: I don't think a semicolon is the only reason this work, as the compiler could possibly mistake the method then for an abstract method. 
There are the reference to the super constructor, and the fact that the class is not denoted as abstract as hints to the compiler, that this is, in fact, a constructor.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh That still doesn't make much sense. You can add logic to C# properties, by simply changing the syntax from >> get; set;  << to get {} and set {} accordingly. Why would it be much different in the case of the constructor? Simply remove the semicolon if necessary and replace with the brackets.

Comment: Sort of, but you can't have abstract constructors anyway, since constructors aren't inherited.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My thoughts exactly. That's another reason why the compiler should be able to differentiate between an abstract method and a constructor being terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: I guess if nothing else though, this leads to consistency. If you see a method declaration that ends with a semicolon, it's an abstract method. If you see a method declaration that ends with `{}`, it's non-abstract (but empty). Maybe the consistency argument is enough?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I wouldn't think so. Especially not in this case. Considering the fact that you are missing the `abstract` keyword, and you have the colon with the `base` keyword. I don't see how the two would be mistaken. Microsoft has implemented single-line functions to use the lambda syntax, which could possibly somehow confuse a few people.

Comment: @Beatsleigher, constructor can't be abstract, it should have body, but this body can be empty.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh I'm not attempting to create an abstract constructor. Quite the opposite.

Comment: @Beatsleigher, ok. So what is a question? Do you want use semicolon instead of curvy brackets? You can't, this syntax is a part of C# specification. Maybe in the future they will add possibility to use semicolon, but now you can't. Just live with it.

Comment: @UladzimirPalekh A little less rude, and reading the question would be appreciable. The question is _why_ it doesn't work. The fact it doesn't is perfectly clear to me. I'm interested in the reasoning behind such a design choice, and as to why it should or possibly shouldn't be implemented.

Comment: @Beatsleigher, I'm sorry, but there is an answer in comments. Constructor should have body, it a part of specification. Body should be placed between curvy brackets. Yes, you can use short syntax for properties, but it is just a syntactic sugar to reduce code in common things as simple properties is very common thing. Yes, theoretically empty constructors can be simplified too but it will create misunderstanding because this syntax will be same as syntax of the abstract method that is very different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of method declarations, `;` doesn't mean "this is an empty method".

On an `abstract` method, it means "there is no method body".

On an `extern` method, it means that the actual code is located elsewhere.

For property getters and setters, it means "the code for this method is automatically generated".

If you want to write an *empty* method body, there's already a means of writing that and it's only one character longer - `{}`.